# How to test window.open in in angular2

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am new to angular testing.
I have a method in my controller which opens a new window like this

```
public goToTermsOfService() {
this.nativeWindow.open(
  'someurl/' +
    this.translate.currentLang +
    '/Home/License',
  '_blank'
);
```

}

How am i supposed to write a unit test for this in angular ?

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a key idea for you.

Try to create a mock method  for `open()` method by using `spyon`, like

```
spyOn(_nativeWindow, 'open')
            .and.callFake(function (param) {
                param.open();
            });
```

So when you test `goToTermsOfService()` via unit test `_nativeWindow` have a mock object instead of real object. That's the way I am using and it;s working good for me.